# jQuery fancy box question

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jQuery fancybox with an iframe. It loads the code from a .php. 
Inside that .php file, I have a button which does a post when clicked.

```
$(".next").click(function() {
                        $.post("update.php", {page: $(this).attr('data-page')}, function(success){
                                $("#dialog").html(success);
                            }
                        );
                 });
```

The issue is that when I click this for the first time it loads up the html, however it does not work the second time. It seems that jQuery is not loaded for the second time as I am using the star-rating and the star-rating is not rendered there as well.

Initially my dialog has some html code in it.

To illustrate, here's how the structure of my page. I have a main.php. I have a button inside main.php that when I click launches an iframe fancy box. The content of this fancy box is loaded from a .php file, called content.php. Inside the content.php I have another button that when clicked does a post to loader.php. loader.php echoes a bunch of html. The jQuery code to post is located at content.php When I click on the button inside the iframe for the second time, it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Fancybox is really just loading a div over your current content, so if the content of that div (the Fancybox "dialog") changes after the DOM is set (in other words, the page is done loading) then the events are not attached to the new content by jQuery. You'd have to modify your code to use the `.live()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of click, you have to use live. Change first line as:

```
$(".next").live('click', function() {
```

Comment: what you mean jQuery star rating issue? click function handles only the matched elements already exist. With live function, it handles the future matched elements which inserted after page loaded first time.